# Expectation of quadratic term with 2 random variables

Tags: statistics, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

I'm trying to understand, why the MSE of two Random Variables $\Theta$ and X is:
$ E[] $ is the expectation and $f_X(x)$ is the probability density function of X

$$ E[(T(X)-\Theta)^2] = E[E[(T(X)-\Theta)^2|\Theta]] = \int_\Theta \int_X (T(x)-\Theta)^2f_{x,\Theta}(x,\theta)dxd\theta$$

$$E[(T(X)-\Theta)^2] = E[T(X)^2-2T(X)\Theta + \Theta^2] \underbrace{=}_{linear}  E[T(X)^2] - 2E[T(X)\Theta]+E[\Theta^2] = \int_X T(x)^2 f_X(x)dx - 2\int_X\int_\Theta T(x)\theta  f_{x,\theta} d\theta dx +\int_\Theta \theta^2 f_\Theta(\theta) d\theta$$

But now I don't know how do I get the equation from above.

Comment: The second line (which is followed by the 3rd line) is not continuing the first line. These are just two different ways of evaluating the expectation, and which one is more convenient to use depends on the situations.

Comment: Why not? How do I come from $E[(T(X)−Θ)^2]$ to $∫_Θ∫_X(T(x)−Θ)^2f_{x,Θ}(x,θ)dxdθ$ ?

Comment: $E[(T(X)−Θ)^2] = ∫_Θ∫_X(T(x)−Θ)^2fx,Θ(x,θ)dxdθ$ is just writing down the definition of expectation when the joint density exists. In only very rare cases (either very advanced or pathological) doesn't the density not exist. Or are you temporarily [too conscious](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) to see how the expectation works? I personally actually have experienced it once.

Comment: Ah ok now I understand what you mean. But I didn't find in my lecture notes this definition, so I tried to use the basic properties (linearity: $E[aX+bY] = aE[X]+bE[Y]$, function of random variable $E[g(X)] = \int g(x)f_X(x)dx $ ) to derive this equation. But I don't know how to handle two different random variables in one function.